# Send unique string with multiple numbers Client/Server TCP

Tags: c, tcp, server, client, message

i am working on a TCP client/server communication in C. Client has to get the number of data(not > 6), get the data and send them to server in a single string message like this: 4 11 21 9 11.
4 is the number of data and 11, 21, 9, 11 are data.

Then, server has to read message, print it and send to client the number of data received(4).

I tried this for client:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus= 0;
    char buffsend[256];
    char buffrecv[256];
    int n, i;
    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;

    if (3 != argc) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <server> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    /* create a streaming socket      */
    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for connecting */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use the IP address sent as an argument for the server address  */
    //bzero(&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer));
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //inet_addr(argv[2], &simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr);
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  connect to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connect successful!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect to address!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
    }





    /* get the message from the server   */



      do {

        printf("get numb of data or terminate(write '0'): ");
        fgets(buffsend,256,stdin);
        n=atoi(buffsend);
        if(n>6) {
          printf("Error\n");

         }
        else {
                for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
                   printf("insert number: ");
                   fgets(buffsend,256,stdin);
                   write(simpleSocket, buffsend, strlen(buffsend)+1);


         }



     } while((n!=0) && (n>0));





    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;

}
```

And this for server:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus = 0;
    char buff[256];
    char message[256];
    int count;

    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;

    if (2 != argc) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for listening */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use INADDR_ANY to bind to all local addresses  */
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  bind to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = bind(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer,sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bind completed!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind to address!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
    }

    /* lets listen on the socket for connections      */
    returnStatus = listen(simpleSocket, 5);

    if (returnStatus == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot listen on socket!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1)

    {

        struct sockaddr_in clientName = { 0 };
    int simpleChildSocket = 0;
    int clientNameLength = sizeof(clientName);

    /* wait here */

        simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);

    if (simpleChildSocket == -1) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot accept connections!\n");
        close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);

    }

        /* handle the new connection request  */
    /* write out our message to the client */


        while(read(simpleChildSocket, buff, 256))
            cont++;
            printf("%s", buff);
        printf("Data received: %d %s\n", cont, buff);



       close(simpleChildSocket);
    }

    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;

}
```

The problem is with the "for" cicle because everytime I insert a number, buffer of server is emptied and prints only the last number received.
Thank you if provide a solution to this.

Comment: Please elaborate the problem. What is `the "for" cicle`? Show sample data etc. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is the cycle                             for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
                                                             printf("insert number: ");
                                                             fgets(buffsend,256,stdin);
                                                               write(simpleSocket, buffsend, strlen(buffsend)+1);

Answer (score 0):

In read call, you might get entire or partial string that you mentioned(4 11 21 9 11)

After each read call you need to parse the data you received, check if you got entire string or partial one, if you get partial one post read again to get rest of data.
After you confirm you got entire data, you need to call write to send 4 back to your client

Then get back to read call again